# Google Datastore deletes and multiple parents

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

I have a data model in which entity `A` contains references to two other entities, `B` and `C`. If either `B` or `C` is deleted, I want `A` to be deleted.

When creating `A`, it's possible to name either `B` or `C` as its parent. Is it also possible to name *both* `B` and `C` as its parents so that if either `B` or `C` is deleted, `A` is also deleted?

In more concrete terms, say search results, a result might have both a `category` and a `region`, say a web page about birds in North America. The result is stored with a reference to its category and region. Later, you want to delete the category `birds` and you want the result also deleted. Likewise, you delete the region `North America` and want the result deleted.

I hate to go on at such length about such a trivial scenario. But it doesn't seem to be covered in any of the Datastore documentation. What am I missing? Is it a basically flawed data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Single-parent limitation:

A child can have only one parent in Datastore. In other words, `A` can only be a child of `B` **OR** `C`, not both. Of course, a parent can have multiple children, though.

#### Alternative:

You can use a `KeyProperty` with `repeated=True` argument and store many Entity keys on it. In Python, this would be like this:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    associated_with = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
    some_other_property = ndb.StringProperty()

a_entity = A(
    associated_with = [b_key, c_key],
    some_other_property = 'any value'
)
a_entity.put()
```

#### Automatically triggering deletes:

Datastore doesn't offer this functionality out of the box, but you can mimic it in your application. Just one idea for implementing in Python, for example, you could extend the Model class with your own delete method (haven't tested this code, it's just for illustration):

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    associated_with = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
    some_other_property = ndb.StringProperty()

    def delete_ext(entity):  # entity object
        if entity.associated_with:
            for associated in entity.associated_with:
                associated.delete()
        entity.key.delete()
```

You may want to wrap all the deletes in a transaction. Beware that a single transaction can operate on up to 25 entity groups.

Comment: Ah, thanks. As I suspected, it is more correct to model a domain using the `repeated` property attribute. This is also more intuitive than trying to hang the model together using single entity references. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Just wondering... what's the purpose of "_ext" in `delete_ext`? To prevent recursion, or collision with the Model namespace?

Comment: It's not necessary to add the "_ext". In the Python NDB library, the [Model class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#class_methods) has no method named delete, you could use it. Personally, I would add something to differentiate from the Key delete() method, but it's just to help to avoid myself (or anyone else in the future) from confusing the custom A.delete() method with A.key.delete() when reading the code.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Thanks.